# How to test android app that uses flashlight?

Tags: android, emulation, flashlight

I'm currently developing an app for android that uses the flash. My miserable problem is that I don't have a device featuring a flashlight... Is there any emulator in the world that shows the flash state?

Thank you guys in advance! 
José.

Comment: are you try the normal android emulator ??

Comment: and also genymotion emulator for android , you can try to apply your code on it

Comment: but the normal android emulator does not show the flashlight state!! And that is what I need to see...

Comment: take look in it this project using android emulator
https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin-samples/tree/master/helloflashlight

Answer (score 3):

There is no emulator that can allow you test the flashlight. You need a real device for it.

You need to add the permission also to your manifest file - "android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"

Answer (score 3):

If you are working with laptop then You can use bluestack to check your application related to flashlight it will work

Answer (score 2):

The android emulator does not work with "flashlight apps".

I was also disappointed to hear this when I started developing my flashlight app quite some time ago. I haven't found a solution either, except for having a development device (my phone) to test the app on.

In general, it helps to have a development device on hand because **the emulator is not always 100% accurate.**

Best of luck.